# Snapshot or Dynaset - which one enhances the performance?

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that retrieves 1000 records and user can add a new record in this form. I want to enhance the performance because the query already needs 5 seconds.

I have read many article about snapshot and Dynaset but I can not conclude from them. Some of them say that snapshot enhances the performance and others say that Dynaset does.

What do you mean?

Comment: It is my answer and I cant mark it as answer :(

Comment: No worries, i've moved my comment to an answer, you should be able to accept it now if you wish, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always depends on the datasource, in most cases "snapshot" is faster because this gives you a read-only view of the data without the indexes coming it to effect. On a "dynaset" Access needs to read the indexes in order to determine how to publish updates if you make any changes to the data. If your user is able to add new records in this view then "snapshot" will not be available to you.